# Red wire is connected to ground screw in my 110 volt receptacle

Tags: electrical, wiring

Why would a red wire be connected to the ground screw in my 110 volt receptacle?  It is in a room addition built in the 1960's.

Romex 12/3 wire. 3 wires total: white, black, red

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 12-3 with ground would be proper I have not seen 12-3 in the colors red ,black,white without a ground but maybe it is out there look close at the back of the box but red as a ground has been a code violation for many years.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of this box please?

Answer (score 1):

That outlet was miswired, and I would be very cautious with all of the wiring in that house. There's no telling what other "shortcuts" were taken.

1. Provide photo(s) of the outlet/setup.
2. Does that Romex also include a bare wire?
3. Does a circuit tester (like below) show the outlet as wired correctly?

   [image]
4. Get yourself a voltage tester.
5. Also get yourself a continuity tester. If possible, **rent or buy a MegOhm
   Meter, AKA "Megger".**
6. Switch off and or unplug everything on that circuit.
7. Switch the breaker off or unplug the fuse at the circuit panel.
8. With a voltage tester, **make sure that no AC is present in the outlet.**
9. The megger should show very high resistance (greater than 200K ohms) between the hot (black) and neutral (white).  If it doesn't, something is still on that circuit or you have a serious problem.
10. The megger should show less than 2 ohms resistance between the neutral (white) and the bare wire (if present).
11. In this case, the megger should also show less than 2 ohms between the neutral and the red wire.
12. Trace the red wire through the house/junction boxes and make sure that it eventually connects to a proper ground wire or the ground buss in the main panel.
13. **If the bare wire is present and grounded, use it instead of the red wire.**
14. If not, and the red wire is properly connected to a ground, then **wrap the ends of the wire with green electrical tape** at every box/or panel where it appears.  This is the code correct (in many jurisdictions) way of indicating the non-standard wire use.
15. If the above conditions are not met, or you can't trace the wire, hire an electrician.

Comment: It may be wired corectly, without using proper wire colors, I have found white used as a hot, ground and grounds used as a neutral and hot in the past although the circuit needs to be verified and re marked inspectors have not required me to replace incorrectly wired branch circuits in 2 states I have worked if identified correctly at source and device locations

Comment: @EdBeal, even if it is electrically correct, it is still wired incorrectly as the wires weren't either colored per code or marked per code.  So at a minimum the correct marking should be applied to the wires (once their functionality is verified).

Comment: Please read more carefully - I said that the Romex has 3 wires. There is NO bare wire. The red wire is only in the room addition - not the rest of the house. The receptacles in the added room have their own breaker.  After confirming that the red is truly the ground I should probably strip off the red coating so as not to confuse anyone in the  future who might rely on color alone.

Comment: @Paul, You provided no pictures and, by the nature and content of your question, asking to verify that there is no bare wire is extraordinarily warranted. **Do not strip off the red insulation** unless you can do it for the entire cable (you can't).  Follow directions, and **follow the required code**.  If the red wire turns out to be a proper ground, you must mark it at both ends with green tape (or an alternative required by your local code).

Comment: I'll post photos for the doubters. Green tape is good idea.

Comment: @Paul, thanks. So for you, steps 1 thru 15 apply -- excluding steps 2 and 13. ... Also note that the Q&A is meant to be useful to other users who actually might have a bare wire in their Romex.